# Assigning a variable to the output of a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

So I'm trying to run a function, while returning its' return value to a variable, so that I can run another function with that information, but separately. I want to know if, when I do this, it actually runs the whole function. 
Example:

```
function a() {
  blah blah blah;
  return b;
}
var c = a();
function d(x) {
  something with c;
}
d(c);
```

When I assign a() to c, does that run a()? or just find the return value, and return it. I would greatly appreciate this! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not finding this very clear. But yes, if you run `a()`, that's a call to `a`.

Comment: Yes, it runs the function.

Comment: well, that's the basic of programming. you call a function using parenthesis, it runs.

Comment: You can’t simply _“find the return value, and return it”_ without running the function. Sure, some engine might optimize certain function calls, and, if a function could be determined to be a pure function with a constant return value, this could even actually happen. But that’s generally not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it runs the a() function and you should be able to use c with the value return by a() in the d(x) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = a()
```

will execute function a, and store the results in the var c.

If you want to refer to the function itself and not what is returned from executing the function, you would write:

```
var c = a
```